# Is it a duplicate content if i use learn more system?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I ask myself a small question, I can't formulate it for google, so I can't find an answer about it apart from several results on duplicate content.

If for example I have on a page, a half text with a read more button ...

And that on a second page I use the same text to start the article. Would this be considered duplicate content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic of duplicate content has changed over the years. Here is one older question: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site). I have written some examples of how Google determines duplicate content, however, I could not find it quickly. Trust me, it would quickly put you at ease. The up-shot is this. Google knows what is duplicate content and what is not.

Your situation, as you describe it, is perfectly normal. The technique of using content snippets is commonly used in blogs to tease a story on the home page or category and tag pages. Google and indeed Bing expect this. Indeed, they fully understand the "Read More" button/link.

What you want to make sure you do are 3 things.

1.

Your original post should have a canonical tag that points to itself.

From the Google page on the topic, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/dresses/green-dresses" />
```

You could use the code example in the `<head>` section of your HTML and change the URL to point to the page itself.

This tells Google this is the original copy of the content.

2.

When you create your content snippet, do not make it too large. Google will understand that this is a content snippet. I cannot recommend a size limit, however, you want it big enough to tease the story and short enough to be a snippet.

Advice: I like avoid cut and paste here. I prefer to write a teaser from scratch.

3.

You can certainly use "Read More" for a button or a link. Make sure it immediately follows the content snippet.

Advice: I avoid "Read More" links and buttons. The reason is simple. Do you really want to rank for the terms "read more"? I don't. Instead, I use either the title of the page you are linking to or a teaser. For example, "Learn more about how eating almonds is good for men's health." is not only a good teaser but could also be the title of the page you link to.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and complete answer. However, for the first point of canonical URLs, I just read on a subject that by putting a canonical tag, this avoids indexing this page on google. Is this really the case? Does that mean that my page with original content snippet is not going to be indexed on google ? Or is only one of the 3 points you mentioned necessary?

Comment: @Meds ***that by putting a canonical tag, this avoids indexing this page on google. Is this really the case?*** Yes and No. The canonical tag only points to the page you prefer Google to consider the original. For example, if your content was stolen and posted elsewhere on the net, the stolen content will not show up in the SERPs. Your page with the snippets will be indexed. The content snippets will not be seen as duplicate. In fact, if this page updates regularly, it may become your top performer in search. You have nothing to worry about. Cheers!!